# Why does line 4 only print out "B move"?

Tags: java, overriding, super

I'm trying to understand this code's outputs. I understand the other outputs except for line 4's.

The code:

```
class A{
    public void move(Object o){
        System.out.println("A move");
    }
    public void keep(String s){
        System.out.println("A keep");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    public void move(Object o){
        System.out.println("B move");
    }
    public void keep(Object o){
        System.out.println("B keep");
    }
}

class C extends B{
    public void move(String s){
        super.move(s);
        System.out.println("C move");
    }
    public void keep(String s){
        super.keep(s);
        System.out.println("C keep");
    }
}

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        A b = new B();
        A c = new C();

        a.move("Test"); //line1

        b.move("Test"); //line2

        b.keep("Test"); //line3

        c.move("Test"); //line4

        c.keep("Test"); //line5
    }
}
```

The output:

```
A move

B move

A keep

B move

A keep
C keep
```

I was expecting line 4 to print out "B move. C move" but instead it just ended at "B move". I thought that it would have the same logic as line 5. Anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: `public void move(String s)` has a different parameter type, so it doesn't override `public void move(Object o)` - and is therefore not called through a reference to `A`

Comment: And similar: `public void keep(Object o)` in `B` has a different parameter type than `public void keep(String s)` in `A` and therefore doesn't override. In `C` the method `public void keep(String s)` overrides `A`s method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloads are determined by the compiler, overrides are done at runtime. A method's "identity" **includes** its parameter types and its return type as well as its name. Therefore:

- B.keep **does not** override A.keep, but B.move *does* override A.move.
- C.move **does not** override B.move/A.move. C.keep overrides A.keep but not B.keep.

Hence, The compiler sees, at line 4, `c.move("Test")`, and determines that this is a call on an expression of type `A` (because you declared variable `c` as `A c;`. Looking just at what A has to offer, there's only one method named `move`, whose signature is `void move(Object)`. So that gets encoded in the class file.: A call to `A.move(Object)`.

Then at runtime, the runtime checks for the most specific implementation of the `void move(Object)` method on the *actual* type of the object that the `c` variable is pointing at, which is in fact an object of type `C`. The most specific implementation of move(Object) is found in B: B has a `void move(Object)` implementation. C has a `void move(String)`, but this doesn't "count" - it does not have the same identity, effectively, it has a different name and has nothing whatsoever to do with A's move(Object) - that they have the same actual method name (`move`) is a coincidence.

Two tips:

- Always use the `@Override` annotation when you intend to override. Had you done so here, the compiler would have told you that e.g. B's `keep(Object o)` method **is not** an override, and it would have also flagged C's move method as erroneous, had you flagged it as `@Override`. (This annotation does not mean 'this method is an override'. It means: If this method doesn't override or implement anything, generate a compile time error. A method whose full signature matches a method in a parent type still overrides it, even without the annotation. It's just compiler-checked documentation, which is a good thing you should use).
- In general do not write the same method name with different variable types if those variable types have a relationship. It results in confusion like this.